# Modifying standard STL containers so support generic queue interface

Tags: c++, stl

I'm interested in creating a function that uses a queue as part of its implementation, but I want to be templated on the type of queue so that it will have different functionality based on what type of queue its templated with.

Here's a basic example:

```
template <typename Queue>
void example()
{
  Queue a;
  a.push(3);
  a.push(1);
  a.push(2);
  while (!a.empty()) {
    cout << a.top() << ' ';
    a.pop();
  }
  cout << flush;
}
```

What I want is for `example<stack<int>>()` to print `2 1 3`, `example<priority_queue<int>>()` to print `3 2 1`, and `example<queue<int>>()` to print `3 1 2`. This works for `stack` and `priority_queue` but unfortunately `queue` doesn't provide `top` and instead provides `front`. Is there an easy way to tell the compiler when it sees `top` on a `queue` to call `front` instead?

The only way around this that I can think of is to follow this question [How to implement generic method for STL containers that haven`t common interface needed for that method using template template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600198/how-to-implement-generic-method-for-stl-containers-that-havent-common-interface), and implement my own local `top` for each of the data types and call that instead. This solution seems super inelegant though, and I'd rather find another way if possible.

Edit: I am using a compiler that supports C++11, gcc 4.7.0 to be exact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the presence of a `top()` and a `front()` member are mutually exclusive, you could create a suitable `top()` helper function which is overloaded on the presence of the respective member:

```
 template <typename Queue>
 auto top(Queue const& queue) -> decltype((queue.top()))
 {
     return queue.top();
 }

 template <typename Queue>
 auto top(Queue const& queue) -> decltype((queue.front()))
 {
     return queue.front();
 }
```

You can then just use `top(a)` to access the current top even if the top is called `front()`. This won't work, however, if a queue has both `front()` and `top()`. A simple fix to this problem is to make the choice of the `front()` version just a bit less attractive to call so it is called if it is the only version but it isn't called if both `top()` and `front()` are available. For example:

```
 template <typename Queue>
 auto top(Queue const& queue, bool) -> decltype((queue.top()))
 {
     return queue.top();
 }

 template <typename Queue>
 auto top(Queue const& queue, int) -> decltype((queue.front()))
 {
     return queue.front();
 }
```

... and then get access to the top element using `top(a, true)`.

Comment: Oh, I missed the double parentheses in my comment :) -- Why not provide a default argument for those additional parameters (or even use an ellipsis)?

Comment: @DyP: The extra argument can't be defaulted as both calls would still be good enough. I had tried to use ellipsis as I thought that would the choice obvious but I think an alternative is only preferred if an argument would ellipsis. Using the extra argument works reliably although it isn't pretty. The presence of `top()` could be made a type trait and then `std::enable_if` could be used to provide the correct choice but I was too lazy to type that option out...

Comment: Right.. for some reason, I thought default arguments would participate in overload resolution. Using an additional template parameter pack however works, if there are only two overloads to select from `template<class T, class...TT>auto top(T const& p, TT...)->decltype((p.top()));`

Comment: This is certainly the most elegant syntax possible for SFINAE.

Comment: In general they don't support both top and front, so this solution does work. It still doesn't seem like the most ideal, but it's certainly much better than the alternatives I've seen. Thanks!